# How to install docker on slurm hpc?

Tags: docker, high-availability, slurm

I have an hpc slurm on ubuntu and I want to install docker or docker rootles. But I can't find anything on official sites, so how could I install docker on a slurm cluster and run containers or if you know another container tool I would be grateful!

Thanks!